# C++ template specialization: union vs struct

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

Say I have a template function:

```
template<typename T> void doit(T const & t)
{
  t.doit();
}
```

It is specialized for primitive types:

```
template<> void doit(int const & i)
{ /* FUN HERE */ }
```

Structures/Classes implement a method to do their stuff:

```
void MyClass::doit(void) const
{ /* EVEN MORE FUN */ ::doit(someMember); }
```

For unions I do have a "general" solution, applyable to any union type. Is there some way for a template to "match on a union" but not a struct / class? Perhaps utilizing SFINAE?

Unfortunately I'm restricted to C++03 and cannot use C++11 or C++14 language features or any (including the std) libraries.

Comment: Boost has [`is_union`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_union.html), if you can't / don't want to use Boost then have a look at how it implements it.

Comment: Hm .. they state that there is no way except for using compiler intrinsics. Nonetheless I still have the hope that SFINAE could work, possibly exploiting the fact that unions must not be base types ...